# The only way to get a File object by letting the user choose a file is MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE?

Tags: android

I want to show a file browser to the user, let him choose an arbitrary file he wants, and read it using the [ZipFile](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/index.html?java/util/zip/ZipFile.html) class. The class requires a File object, not an InputStream.

If my research is correct, the in-built file choosers (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, etc) only provide a stream, not a File, right? Even if I get the file name from the chooser and have acquired READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE from the user, it seems that in recent Android versions, the API only allows "only media" and reading files of other types seems to fail.

If I have also acquired MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, then it works, but that shows a scary warning like following to the user.

> Allow this app to access, modify, and delete files on the device or any connected storage devices? This app may access files without asking you.

That seems to be an unnecessarily broad permission when all I want to is a read-only access to `File` for a file that the user has explicitly chosen in the file browser. There is no other way than acquiring MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, is that right? I want to make it sure, because it sounds weird. Even a very restricted environment like a web browser, the browser does not require any special permission or show any warning for reading a file that the user has explicitly selected, and the same was true for UWP app.

Comment: `choose an arbitrary file he wants, and read it using the ZipFile class. ` Sorry but that does not sound ok. What should a zip class do with an arbitrary file i wonder

Comment: `the in-built file choosers (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, etc) only provide a stream, not a File, right?` Np, no stream or File but an Urii

Comment: `and have acquired READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE from the user, it seems that in recent Android versions, the API only allows "only media" and reading files of other types seems to fail.`Nothing of that comes true. You dont need that permission and every file choosen by the user your app can read.

Comment: In short: Just read from the uri you got. Very simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If my research is correct, the in-built file choosers (ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT, etc) only provide a stream, not a File, right?

Correct. After all, the user can choose something that you cannot access via the filesystem, either due to permissions or due to the fact that it simply isn't on the filesystem (e.g., cloud storage, SMB/CIFS file server).

IOW, what you refer to as "file choosers" are not limited to what you seem to be thinking of as files.

> If I have also acquired MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, then it works

I do not know what "it" is. You cannot hack into Google Drive to get a `File` object using `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, for example. Nor can you get a `File` object for a document contained as a BLOB in an encrypted database, etc.

> There is no other way than acquiring MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, is that right?

You cannot do what you want even with `MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`. A `Uri` is not a file.

Your options are:

1. Copy the content identified by the `Uri` to some file that you control (e.g., in `getCacheDir()`), so you can use `ZipFile`.
2. Relax the `ZipFile` constraint. For example, perhaps you could use `ZipInputStream`, or find a third-party ZIP reader that supports `InputStream` (such as [this](https://github.com/srikanth-lingala/zip4j#extract-files-with-zipinputstream) or [this](https://github.com/bitstorm/tiny-zip#using-streams)). You can get an `InputStream` on the content identified by the `Uri` via `openInputStream()` on `ContentResolver`.
3. Relax the "in-built file choosers" constraint, and implement your own "file chooser" with files that your app can read on the filesystem. That way, you are guaranteed that you can use `File`, since you used `File` to get to them in the first place.

Comment: By "it", I meant creating a File object using the physical path, and passing it to the ZipFile class to read it. I was originally trying to use ZipInputSteam, but random access to entries seemed impossible due to the fact that Input Stream has no set/get position, unlike C#'s stream. Is there any way to get a seekable data source from the system's file chooser? If not, probably none of other Zip libraries could support random access.

Comment: @DamnVegetables: "Is there any way to get a seekable data source from the system's file chooser?" -- no, sorry. "If not, probably none of other Zip libraries could support random access" -- I agree. It wasn't clear from your question if your objective was to unZIP the entire ZIP archive or only access pieces of it. Since you only want pieces, option #2 isn't a good choice, leaving you with #1 or #3.

Comment: For #3, even if I use [a third-party file chooser library](https://android-arsenal.com/tag/35), it is still part of my app and subject to the same permission requirements, isn't it? That is, I still need that MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to make that third-party library allow the user to choose any file type (not just "media"), right?

Comment: @DamnVegetables: "it is still part of my app and subject to the same permission requirements, isn't it?" -- yes. "I still need that MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission to make that third-party library allow the user to choose any file type (not just "media"), right?" -- what you have access to via `MediaStore` and filesystem APIs depends on the specific directory. However, at least with option #3, you correctly limit yourself to not only you have permission to access but is available using a specific API that you wish to use (`ZipFile`).